# Is Schleyer's first sketch of Volapük available as a reprint?

Tags: history, resource-request, volapuk

Johann Martin Schleyer published the first sketch of Volapük in 1879 in a rather obscure catholic newsletter named *Die Sionsharfe*. This newsletter isn't easily accessible, as far as I know. Is this first sketch available as a reprint in some more accessible work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my big surprise the relevant issue of *Sionsharfe* is now digitised and freely available from *Digitale Bibliothek München*. The first sketch of Volapük at this moment still named only *Weltsprache* or *Allsprache*, the word *Volapük* itself can be found a few month later, occurs [in Nr. 35, Vol. IV (1879) Beilage](http://daten.digitale-sammlungen.de/0009/bsb00096281/images/index.html?id=00096281&groesser=&fip=yztsewqeayayztsqrsxdsydweayaqrs&no=7&seite=9) as a supplement.

What a fascinating document!

Following issues of *Sionsharfe* also contain shorter or longer fragments of Volapük, unfortunately the digisat ends with Nr 48 (1880), there are four more years missing.